# How do I modify the jinja_loader.searchpath in a quart application?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, quart

I have this code:

```
app=Quart(__name__)

print(app.jinja_loader.searchpath)
app.jinja_loader.searchpath.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),app.config["BASE_TEMPLATE_FOLDER"]))
print(app.jinja_loader.searchpath)
```

`app.config["BASE_TEMPLATE_FOLDER"]` returns the string path to the directory of my `base.html`. The pathing is correct but for some reason `app.jinja_loader.searchpath` is not updating. Its a list so it should be mutable but it doesn't change whether I use `.append()`, `+=[]` or whether I completely assign it to a new list.

However, when I run

```
print(app.jinja_loader.searchpath+[os.path.join(os.getcwd(),app.config["BASE_TEMPLATE_FOLDER"])])
```

It outputs what I want it to output which is a list containing the path I want to append.

I must update the `jinja_loader.searchpath` because by default it only points to the main template folder when I also need it to point to another template folder containing the `base.html`.

I was using `flask` before but I only just changed my project to run using `quart`. Changing the searchpath on flask worked as expected but only after changing to quart is when this problem began occurring.

ChatGPT suggested I reassign the `FileSystemLoader`:

```
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader
app.jinja_loader=FileSystemLoader(app.jinja_loader.searchpath+[os.path.join(os.getcwd(),app.config["BASE_TEMPLATE_FOLDER"])])
```

But then I get the error: `AttributeError: can't set attribute 'jinja_loader'`

This is a baffling situation considering no errors are being raised, its just the searchpath won't change, which then induces an error of my `base.html` not being found but thats irrelevant since my pathing is correct as I mentioned before.

Any help would be much appreciated.